# Getting the Device ID before running ViewController code in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I have this peace of code to get device id :

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    NSString *devicetokenRN = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", deviceToken];
    devicetokenRN = [devicetokenRN stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    devicetokenRN = [devicetokenRN stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];
    devicetokenRN = [devicetokenRN stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];


    // send device token for APNS without spaces or <>
    DeviceID *DeviceIdentifier = [[DeviceID alloc ] init];
    // sending it to the Device.h
    [DeviceIdentifier setDeviceID:devicetokenRN];
}
```

I need to retrieve this DeviceID as the first thing on my ViewController. As it doesn't do this function before it runs the view controller, because if I use NSlog in the ViewController it is NULL as it hasn't run this first. I need to get some variable like this first before it runs the UITableView. Any ideas would be brilliant thanks.

Comment: The registerForRemoteNotificationTypes method is executed fromdidFinishLaunchingWithOptions , is this the earliest place I can run it from, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AppDelegate, you can save the deviceToken value in NSUserDefaults like

put these line in didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken method in appdelegate.m like this

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken

{

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:deviceToken forKey:@"DeviceToken"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

}
```

also put this line of code in your view Controller.m and In ViewDidLoad method

and Retrieve that value.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"DeviceToken"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get and store your **deviceId**  in `NSUserDefaults`

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
  NSUUID *identifierForVendor = [[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor];
  NSString *deviceId = [identifierForVendor UUIDString];
  NSUserDefaults *userRegistrarionDetails = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  [userRegistrarionDetails setObject:deviceId forKey:@"deviceID"];
  [userRegistrarionDetails synchronize];
}
```

And you can get anywhere in your whole project by

```
NSUserDefaults *userRegistrarionDetails = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString * deviceId = [userRegistrarionDetails objectForKey:@"deviceID"];
NSLog(@"%@", deviceId);
```

Comment: Does this mean it will be available in ViewController straight the way ?

Comment: The identifierForVendor is not the identifier you need for sending push notifications to the phone...